# Java collections: Sorting a list of values according to a separate list of keys

Tags: java, list

I have two lists. Each key in the keys list corresponds to a value in the value list. The two lists are assumed to be the same size. I need to sort both lists based on the keys list.

I tried the following, but obviously it would not work, as it would mess up the key-value associations. I just have no idea what else to do, aside from writing my own sort implementation.

```
// Would mess up the key-value associations
    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(this.keys);
        Collections.sort(this.values);
    }

    /* Example: 
        this.keys = (2, 1, 4)
        this.values = ("value for 2", "value for 1", "value for 4")
        this.sort()
        this.keys = (1, 2, 4)
        this.values = ("value for 1", "value for 2", "value for 4") */
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I would prefer to stick with the built-in sort functions, as opposed to writing my own. Also I cannot change the underlying data structures.

Comment: Include a sample input with expected output. Also, why not just use a *Map*? It seems ideal for your solution.

Comment: Okay will do. And because I can't change the data structures I'm working with. It's for an assignment and would break the autograder. Plus a bunch of code already depends on it.

Comment: How do you associate both list wrt key-value pairs?

Comment: Not sure if this is the question you were asking, but whenever a key-value pair is added, each is added onto the end of its respective list. So their indices will always correspond. At least until a sort function messes them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you say, you need to keep both lists, you could try something like the following:

```
// Create a map that orders its data.
Map<Integer, String> tmp = new TreeMap<>();

// Put your data into this structure and let it sort the data for you.
for (int i=0; i<keys.size(); i++) {
    tmp.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
}

// Clear your original lists.
keys.clear()
values.clear();

// Put the data back into your lists - but sorted this time.
for (Integer key : tmp.keySet()) {
    keys.add(key);
    values.add(tmp.get(key));
}
```